# Copy Data in Azure Data Factory is slow

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am using Azure Data Factory. I have a `Copy Data` task that takes 7 seconds for a file with 17 kb. I wold like to copy from one folder to on subfolder on the same folder. I have my files in my Azure DL v2.

This is my `Copy File`

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

this is execution log

[image]

As you can see, 7 seconds to copy a csv file with 217 rows and less than 20kb. I can do the same things faster in SSIS. Why ADF is too slow?

Comment: What type of integration runtime are you using for the data sets?

Comment: @Cedersved I have used AutoResoulvedIntegrationRunTime. Do i need to create an other type of Integration runtime?

Comment: Have you tried to use a custom value for *Data Integration Unit* instead of *Auto*?

Comment: @Andrea yes even with 32 it takes still 15 second to copy 217 rows with 20 columns for file size 18kb

Comment: hi,does my answer helps you?

Answer (score 1):

I understand concerning the performance of ADF execution is a very common issue. If you have any channels to contact Azure Support ADF team(the help feature on the portal),that will be the fastest,detailed and the most official way.

Here on the forum, i only could provide some official suggestions with you which is mentioned in the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting).Since you said you are using Auto IR, which is Azure IR actually.

1.Follow the [performance tuning tips](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#performance-tuning-tips) to try another region for testing.

[image]

2.Follow the suggestions of [troubleshooting copy activity on Azure IR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance-troubleshooting#troubleshoot-copy-activity-on-azure-ir).